# Problem with bytes32 values

Tags: solidity, truffle, bytes32

I am facing problem with bytes32.

Here is my sample contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

  contract Test {

    bytes32 public input;
    function test(bytes32 _in) public {
    input = _in;
  }
}
```

The problem is in truffle dev, no matter how I run the test function, the input value is the same. For example, if I run:

> MyContract.deployed().then(inst => { inst.test(12, {from: >web3.eth.accounts[0]}) });

Then I get the result:

> truffle(develop)> MyContract.deployed().then(inst => { return >inst.input.call() });
>   '0xc000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

Also, if I run:

> MyContract.deployed().then(inst => { inst.test("12", {from:
>   web3.eth.accounts[0]}) });

The result is the same:

> MyContract.deployed().then(inst => { return inst.input.call() });
>   '0xc000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

I don't think it's normal..
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bytes are represents as hex value. In your case 0xc of base10 is 12.

In web3js, based on ABI method it will convert value into its corresponding datatype and transmit data to network. Some times in javascript big integers/hex values are represents as a string. Before sending to actual network, web3js will convert to eq values.

That means "12" of string is converted into integer and converted into hex value.

"12" of string type but its numeric type(because it contains only 0-9 values) so web3js will convert into integer type converted into 12. 12 Hex representation is 0xc. But you mention its bytes32. It will pad 32 bit. So final hex string would be 0xc000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Use `web3.utils.fromAscii(string)` will convert into string bytes(hex string) [1 eq:0x31 and 2 eq: 0x32]

Try to change below line for string

> ```
>   MyContract.deployed().then(inst => {        
>      inst.test(web3.fromAscii("123"), {from:web3.eth.accounts[0]}) 
>   });
> ```

Your output would be bytes32 [Because 32byte padding]
0x3132000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Get value as a string:

> ```
>   MyContract.deployed().then(inst => {        
>      web3.toAscii(inst.input())
>   });
> ```

Comment: Is there a standard way to get the correct value entered from client-javascript? 
eg. If I call test("12") I would like to convert the result in a way that I get "12" back.

Comment: I noticed that if I call the function with web3.fromAscii("12") then I can convert the result using web3.utils.toAscii and get 12.

Comment: Yes your correct. Thats what we need to show to user right... What is your qus?

Comment: What if I pass int to the test function?

Comment: What data you want to save? Int or string. Both are different... for int i'll recommend to use u/int its uses less gas, Where is case of bytes EVM will take more gas to execute.

Comment: The contract manages bytes32. I want to handle both int and string. We already found how to handle strings. How can I manage integers?

Comment: In Web3js reserve first byte for datatype identification. For eg: 0x01 for string, 0x00 for int. While retrieving value back in web3js check hex string is starting with 0x01 then convert in to string otherwise int.

Comment: Passing integer 12 to test function results in 0x0c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000. How can I convert it to int in web3js?
web3.toDecimal returns wrong result because of the zeros at the end..

Comment: I guess 1st byte is for datatype representation, var data = "0x"+str.substring(2); web3.toDecimal(data)//

Comment: I think that's wrong..anyway, I guess I'll stick to string only..thanks for the help